# Modified Bubble Sort to prevent extra comparison

Tags: bubble-sort

I modified Bubble sort so that it stops the iteration if it doesn't find any comparison at any instance. I am using a boolean to check if the comparison is happening or not. If it doesn't, then I'm breaking the loop. Your views??

```
public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] arr){
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
            boolean comparisonOccured = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length-i-1; j++) {
                if (arr[j+1]<arr[j]) {
                    int temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = temp;
                    comparisonOccured = true;
                }
            }
            if(!comparisonOccured){
                break;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: Every swap now has an extra assignment, this is not very expensive, but it is also not free. Every pass through the list has an extra check, which again is not very expensive, but again not free.  In the cases where you don't break out early (or do break out early, but not early enough) you made it slower. Whether that's worth it depends on how often you break out early, how much extra overhead you incurred, and how much time you saved. That's a function of how sorted you data is to begin with. You need to profile your algorithm against the structure of your data.

Comment: Also, your variables (temp and comparisonOccured) are constantly going in and out of scope, potentially requiring unnecessary memory allocation and de-allocation.  Initialise them both Before you start the loops, so don't keep reallocating the memory for them.

Comment: The main problem with this attempted optimisation is that bubble sort is front loaded, that is the first pass is the most expensive. If you're sorting a list of 10 items the first pass does up to nine swaps, the last pass only does one swap. That's 9+8+...+2+1 swaps in total (max swaps = 45). So save one third of the swaps you need to stop 5 passes early (5+4+3+2+1=15). That's more than half. Yet, your small additional overhead was added to every swap. Unless you regularly stop Very early, the overhead is rarely worth it. (Useful only if "a couple" of values are out of place.)

Comment: As I see it if the iteration was supposed to happen from 0 to 20 and the list is sorted after 5 iterations only, then the other 15 iterations of the outer and inner loop are saved along with comparisons inside the inner loop. Talking about the overhead issue, iterating 15 times is way more time consuming activity than initializing any bool value as true and false.

Comment: Agreed. But only passing over the list five times out of twenty requires a very well ordered list to begin with.  Even then, without the optimisation you'd do 190 swaps (19+18+..+2+1) and with the optimisation still do 85 swaps. Do many more than five passes over the list and the overhead exceeds the benefit. Which is why you need to profile the Data as much as the algorithm.  (This is not a new subject, just Google it.)